# javascript geolocation and googlemaps

Tags: javascript, geolocation, google-maps

I'm hoping that somebody can help me out on what I feel is an easy answer but I just can't get it to work out.

I'm trying to trap the geolocation lat and long and place it into the google maps api

So far I have

```
var myOptions = {
     zoom:7,
     trips:1,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
   directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

   var request = {
       origin: 'newyork' 
       destination: 'deleware',
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
   };
```

This works fine for what I want. However I want to be able to change `origin` to the users lat long using 
the following script from google.maps.api.

their code is:

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
      var placeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: initialLocation,
        map: map,
      });
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation();
  }

  function handleNoGeolocation() {
    initialLocation = newyork;
    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
  }
```

I want to pull out the

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
```

and allocate it to two 2 variables, `myLat` and `myLong`.
I then want to be able to change my orignal script from

```
var request = {
       origin: 'newyork' 
       destination: 'deleware',
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
   };
```

to

```
var request = {
       origin: myLat,myLong
       destination: 'deleware',
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
   };
```

Does this make sense..?

I'm currently having a pig with it and as I'm not a JS developer it's what I think should be a simple bit of coding that I'm losing the battle with..

Any thoughts..?

cheers douglas for the prompt reply.

I have found this example website from a previous question asked which sheds a bit of light. site is http://npdoty.name/location/

His example goes as follows:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lon = position.coords.longitude;
  var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(lat, lon));

  var jsMap = new GMap2(document.getElementById("jsMap"));
  jsMap.addOverlay(marker);
},function(error){
//use error.code to determine what went wrong
});
```

Can I break out of this example and do something similar to:

```
var request = {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lon = position.coords.longitude;
  var myOrigin = new Gorigin(new GLatLng(lat, lon));

   origin: myOrigin, 
   destination: 'deleware',
   travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
```

};

many thanks

Comment: You need to move `var request = {` _inside_ the `getCurrentPosition` callback. You might want to read up on how callbacks work, but basically you're going to do all of the work that you have in your other test code as the response to getting the user's location. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that may be causing a problem is the way you're trying to pass the myLat and myLong variables.

The value passed to origin needs to be a LatLng object.

i.e.

```
var myLat = "12.345";
var myLng = "54.321";
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLng);

var request = {
    origing: myLatLng,
    desitination...
    etc.
}
```

The biggest problem being that in order to pass the values, you need it to be formatted as such:

```
var request = {
    something: value,
    somethingElse: anotherValue,
    evenMore: bigValue
}
```

Note the commas after each line.  This breaks in your example because of where you're placed yours in the origin value, thus confusing the property.

I'll keep looking at it, but hopefully this helps.